# How to efficiently find relations between html nodes with vanillaJS

Tags: javascript, dom

I have several html nodes at various locations and depths in the DOM.
I need to efficiently sort them according to their location in the DOM regardless of each of their depths.

It should be implemented using VanillaJS, no jQuery and the likes.

For instance, given the following tree:

```
<body>
   <div>
      <div id="a1b"></div>
   <div>
      <div>
         <div id="c1d"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="e1f"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="g1h"></div>
</body>
```

Let's say we have a function that received the four html elements that have ids in a random order, the function should return those elements by the order of appearance within the DOM, namely an array similar to this: `[a1b node, c1d node, e1f node, g1h node]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Node.compareDocumentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition), which is [how jQuery does it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/external/sizzle/dist/sizzle.js#L875), preferentially:

```
const nodes = [
    document.getElementById('a1b'),
    document.getElementById('c1d'),
    document.getElementById('e1f'),
];

nodes.sort((a, b) =>
    a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING ?
        -1 : 1);
```

```js
const shuffle = arr => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const j = i + Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - i));
        const t = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = t;
    }

    return arr;
};

const nodes = shuffle(Array.from(document.body.getElementsByTagName("*")));

console.log(nodes.map(node => node.nodeName));

nodes.sort((a, b) =>
    a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING ?
        -1 : 1);

console.log(nodes.map(node => node.nodeName));
```

```html
<div>
  <section>
    <header></header>
    <span></span>
    <footer></footer>
    <table><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to check `CONTAINED_BY`, when that is set then `FOLLOWING` will be set as well

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`compareDocumentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition):

```
elements.sort(function(a, b) {
    var p = a.compareDocumentPosition(b);
    return Boolean(p & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING)
         - Boolean(p & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is nice approach:

```js
var randomNodes = [document.getElementById('c1d'),document.getElementById('a1b'),document.getElementById('e1f')]
var sorted = document.querySelectorAll(randomNodes.map(el=>'#'+el.id).join(', '));
console.log(sorted);
//if you want standard array:
console.log([...sorted]);
```

```html
<div>
      <div id="a1b"></div>
   <div>
      <div>
         <div id="c1d"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="e1f"></div>
```

Comment: Indeed a nice approach, I understand querySelectorAll returns the elements by their order within the DOM? The documentation says it returns them by "using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes", so that's what it means?... Also I'm wondering what will be more efficient this or the proposed compareDocumentPosition method